# Some PHP guidance re a multi store site please

Tags: magento-1.9, php, price

I have a multi store site a retail and a wholesale site. The wholesale site requires that out of stock, cart and price not be shown whereas the retail site should display this information.

I located info on how to do this by editing the php files however the instructions will affect all my stores what kind of additional info can i apply to the changes to specify what store the edits apply to?

Here's an example of an edit to remove price for guests
`<?php if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){echo '<span class="login_for_price"><strong>Login to See Price</strong></span>br>';return;}?>"`

from  http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-hide-prices-and-add-to-cart-button-for-non-logged-in-visitors.html#gref

@Aric Watson
see my reply in comments

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could base it off of the current store ID. For example

```
if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId() == [APPROPRIATE STORE] {
    {echo '<span class="login_for_price"><strong>Login to See Price</strong></span>br>';return;}?>
}
```

... where `[APPROPRIATE STORE]` is the id of the store that should see the content.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713042/how-to-get-store-information-in-magento) for more details.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried your recommend and it didn't work the original code I posted does work but applies the change to both websites. This is what I tried store id 2 verified in the backend

`<?php if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId() == 2 {if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){echo '<span class="login_for_price"><strong>Login to See Price</strong></span>br>';return;}?>"
} ?>`

please confirm proper syntax